# Is using Kali Linux in corporate enviroment safe?

Tags: metasploit, kali-linux

Does Kali Linux contain audited software which is designed to aid security and basically does not contain any backdoors?

Is this some sort of professional software or compilation of various tools from non-professional background?

Should I be using Kali Linux or should I use something else like Metasploit?

Does Kali Linux have history of having some backdoors or would it allow some 3rd party to access audited systems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kali is a community-built distro full of security tools from both organisations and individuals. It is not designed to be used as a day-to-day operating system. It's a quick-start, throw-away distro for security testing.

Metasploit and Kali Linux are entirely different things. In fact, Metasploit is installed on Kali by default. I suggest you read up on what they do and how, to better understand their function.

As far as I know, Kali has never had any explicit backdoors. The tools themselves, like any other software, have had security issues along the way. This is normal.

If you want reassurance, I work as a pentester, and pretty much everyone on my team has a Kali VM installed on their testing system. The same goes for every pentester I know in other companies.

Answer (score 0):

In short: Yes, you should be using Kali.

However, Kali contains lots of software from a non-professional background. Probably for any definition of non-professional, but definitely when it comes to earning money with it.

This is not really an issue because even for professional software you don't get any kind of security guarantees. Also, what applies to Kali applies to pretty much every other Linux distribution as well.

You should probably run Kali in a VM as mentioned by Polynomial.